# Select2 adding an extra empty tag in multiselect mode

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 in multiselect mode. when i select an element it is adding an extra empty string with it `<option value="? string: ?"></option>`

```js
var app= angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("test",function($scope){
          $(".select").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            data:[],
            query: function (query) {
                if (query.term) {

                    var data = { results: [] }, i, j, s;
                    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                        s = "";
                        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) { s = s + query.term; }
                        data.results.push({ id: query.term + i, text: s });
                    }
                    query.callback(data);
                }
            }
        });
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
  <div ng-controller="test">
        <select class="select" ng-model="mysel" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px"></select>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Edit:**
@Sappy Goofy Ran into new issue edited the above code accordingly. Made the data array empty and added a query. It still showing that error

**Edit:**
after adding `multiple="multiple"` to `<select class="select" ng-model="mysel" data-multiple="true" style="width:300px"></select>` it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weird after adding `data-multiple="true"` to `<select class="select" ng-model="mysel" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px"></select>` it worked. edited the code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

change `<select>` to `<select2>`

Comment: It did worked but with query it still has that issue, edited the code accordingly. Modified the data array empty and added a query option. Actually i used data array previously so that the sample i made looks simple.

Comment: i think its because of mixing jquery and angularjs....angular js has its own way of implementing select2...and sry I couldn't resolve your issue.... try something as show [here](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-select2)